# VBA Format function is ignored

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code:

```vb
Sub NewSummary()
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    iWorking = 3
    iTotal = 4
    dPercent = iWorking / iTotal
    pPercent = Format(dPercent, Percent)
    sWorking = iWorking & " / " & iTotal
    sWorking = Format(sWorking)
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = sWorking
    ws.Cells(2, 1).Value = pPercent
End Sub
```

The output that I expect is:
3 / 4, 75.00%

But what I get is:
4-Mar, 0.75

Excel is overriding the "3 / 4" string and assuming I want a date. How do I suppress that? And why is the Format function not converting 0.75 to 75.00%?

Comment: Is your output in a cell, or in the immediate window? If in a cell you may want to check your cell formatting.

Comment: Where is `Percent` declared or assigned in your code? Hint: it's not. So it's an empty variant. You should `Dim` all variables (using `Option Explicit` at the top of modules will help enforce this, and there are IDE settings you can toggle to make this your default).

Comment: @Dean - in 2 cells, A1 and A2 of Sheet 1

Comment: @DavidZemens According to https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/format_string.php, 
Format("0.981", "Percent")
Result: '98.10%'
So that's what I did.

Comment: That's not what you did though. You did `Percent` (which as an empty variant evaluates to `""` or `vbNullString`), which is **not** `"Percent"` :)

Answer (score 2):

you can't format a string like that. THe spaces around the `/` are a problem, but more generally, formatting `"3/4"` as a string literal relies on some implicit type conversion, and in this case it's assumed to be a date string (representing March 4 in US Locale), which is why you get date-like results.

Do simply:

```
Option Explicit

Sub NewSummary()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Dim iWorking As Long, iTotal As Long
    Dim dPercent As Double
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    iWorking = 3
    iTotal = 4
    dPercent = iWorking / iTotal
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = Format(dPercent, "0.00%")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[Named numeric formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications#named-numeric-formats) are supported, but they're not language-level keywords you can use just like any other variable. As David stated above, `Percent` is just an undeclared local variable holding a `Variant/Empty` value (which means your module is missing `Option Explicit`).

Supply the named format in a string literal:

```
pPercent = Format(dPercent, "Percent")
```

While this works, I personally prefer to use [explicit number formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57526626/1188513), that way you have explicit and full control on the number format; for example if you want a single decimal, or need more than two, using a named format won't cut it.